# one-sample t-test on zero variance sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, biostatistics, small-sample

I have to compare many gene-expression values between a group of 3 patients and a control patient. I choose to apply the one sample t-test (`ttest_1samp` from python `scipy` package) to obtain a list of significant differential expressed genes.

The problem is that in many cases I have that the gene in exam is not expressed in any of the 3 study patients, while it is expressed in the control patient. In this case the test produce an infinite t-statistic and a null p-value because the variance of the reference population is:

$$ V\{0,0,0\}=0 $$

and so the probability to observe a value different from the mean (0) is:

$$ P(x\neq0|t(\nu, 0, 0))=0 $$

I think that, under this condition, the one-sample t-test is not the best choice. Is there an alternative statistical test that I can perform?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: You have a total of 4 people in your sample, 3 in the treatment group and 1 in the control "group"? And the gene that you are trying to compare is constant in one group? How many genes do you have?

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, exactly. I have 3 vs 1. I have 38'496 genes. 16'828 genes are constant (zero expression) in the 3 patients group, but some of these 16'828 genes (about 1'500) are not zero in the control patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have a **tiny** sample. With 3 samples your tests would be underpowered even if your data would not be constant. To convince yourself, here's an example that uses a one-sample $t$-test with $H_1$ that $\mu > 0$ for three samples drawn from Gaussian distribution with $\mu=1$

  ```
  > mean(replicate(5000, t.test(rnorm(3, 1), alternative="greater")$p.value) < 0.05)
  [1] 0.3182
  ```

  As you can see, the test was non-significant (at 0.05 level) in 70% of cases.
- The test to work needs to have a notion of the variability of your data. It learns it from the data. If your sample is constant, there are two possibilities, either the variance *is* zero and in such case the answer is trivial, or it can be *anything* higher than zero, but we have no way of knowing. Unless you would *know* what the variability is, statistical methods could fail.
- If you have three samples, honestly the best you can do is a descriptive summary *"all the three observations were zeros"* and let the readers decide what they take from it. For a statistical solution, you need more data.
- Finally, if you can come up with a reasonable, informative prior, you could use a Bayesian approach where the prior would drag the estimate for the variance away from zero. But again, you have only three samples, a descriptive summary probably makes more sense. With the Bayesian approach, here the result would tell more about your choice of the prior than the data. (So it boils down to *if you know the variance*.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you except for the first point: I think that, although the group variance is zero, you can properly apply non-parametric tests (example Mann Withney rank test). Unfortunately, as you have already said, the statistical power is not enough to obtain a significant p-value from a non-parametric test.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco if all the values are the same, ranks would be equally meaningless.